# Azure Databricks Jupyter Notebook Python and R in one cell

Tags: python, r, azure, jupyter-notebook, databricks

I have some code (mostly not my original code), that I have running on my local PC Anaconda Jupyter Notebook environment. I need to scale up the processing so I am looking into Azure Databricks. There's one section of code that's running a Python loop but utilizes an R library (stats), then passes the data through an R model (tbats). So one Jupyter Notebook cell runs python and R code. Can this be done in Azure Databricks Notebooks as well? I only found documentation that lets you change languages from cell to cell.

In a previous cell I have:

```
%r libarary(stats)
```

So the library stats is imported (along with other R libraries). However when I run the code below, I get

> NameError: name 'stats' is not defined

I am wondering if it's the way Databricks wants you to tell the cell the language you're using (e.g. %r, %python, etc.).

My Python code:

```
for customerid, dataForCustomer in original.groupby(by=['customer_id']):
    startYear = dataForCustomer.head(1).iloc[0].yr
    startMonth = dataForCustomer.head(1).iloc[0].mnth
    endYear = dataForCustomer.tail(1).iloc[0].yr
    endMonth = dataForCustomer.tail(1).iloc[0].mnth

    #Creating a time series object
    customerTS = stats.ts(dataForCustomer.usage.astype(int),
                      start=base.c(startYear,startMonth),
                      end=base.c(endYear, endMonth), 
                      frequency=12)
    r.assign('customerTS', customerTS)

    ##Here comes the R code piece
    try:
        seasonal = r('''
                    fit<-tbats(customerTS, seasonal.periods = 12, 
                                    use.parallel = TRUE)
                    fit$seasonal
                 ''')
    except: 
        seasonal = 1

    # APPEND DICTIONARY TO LIST (NOT DATA FRAME)
    df_list.append({'customer_id': customerid, 'seasonal': seasonal})
    print(f' {customerid} | {seasonal} ')

seasonal_output = pa.DataFrame(df_list)
```

Comment: I think you can only change language from cell to cell in a Jupyter / Databricks notebook, not mix languages within a cell. You could try installing RStudio Open Source on the Databricks cluster, and from within an R notebook, mix Python and R as you want, which is supported through the [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) R package.

Answer (score 1):

If you change languages in databricks you will not be able to get the variables of the previous language